# Does digiKam supports RAW files of Canon G16?

Tags: image-processing

When I open an RAW file of my Canon G16 camera (.cr2 suffix) with digiKam 3.5.0, the colors are wrong and there are black margins. What settings must be done in digiKam to process the file or does digiCam not support Canon?  RawTherapee 4.2 works fine, but I want to use digiKam.

Answer (score 1):

digikam 3.5 is very old. Current version is 4.12.0 with 4.13.0 due out in the next few days.

You can get the latest, greatest version along with needed updated libraries thanks to Philip Johnsson and his extra ppa: https://launchpad.net/~philip5/+archive/ubuntu/extra

Comment: Works with 4.13.0.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:

[Problem with processing .CR2 format in Linux | Photography Stack Exchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56062/problem-with-processing-cr2-format-in-linux)

Canon G16 Raw format is supported with Rawtherapee 4.2. You have to upgrade manually, if your Linux distribution has shipped an older one.

On my Kubuntu 14.04, I have added the ppa repository and upgraded. First it fails, but after a second try, it works (don't know why).